# HALT (python 3) a music file?

Tags: python, tkinter, audio-player

The user has limited time to solve a problem. On the program, I run a music file at the same time as a GUI (tkinter) timer, and they both finish when the time is up. Some users may finish EARLY. I want to make the music stop when they close the timer window. 'winsound' does not accept 'stop()', and I am having no success with 'winsound.SND_PURGE'. This is more complicated than I thought. I tried this:

```
# python 3.5     

winsound.PlaySound('The Countdown.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

root = Tk() # IMAGINE this is a box with a number ticking down
root.mainloop()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", winsound.SND_PURGE) # nothing happens :(
```

Is there a way of using flags? Perhaps an alternative audio-file player? Anything?

Let me know if you do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`winsound.SND_PURGE` is just an integer constant, that happens to have the value of 64 (and furthermore, is documented as "not supported on modern Windows platforms").  What were you expecting `root.protocol()` to do with it?  You need to pass a function to be called when the window is closed.  It looks like:

```
lambda: winsound.PlaySound(None, 0)
```

would be a suitable function for stopping sound playback, although I haven't actually tested it.

I think you're also going to need to add `winsound.SND_ASYNC` to your original PlaySound call's flags, or your window won't even open until the sound is finished.

Comment: There's an error once I close the window: 'can't invoke "wm" command: application has been destroyed'. Is there a way around that?

Comment: My bad: I put the mainloop first. But now I have another problem. When I click the cross to close the window, the sound stops. But the window stays open. When I added 'root.destroy' inside the 'root.protocol' there was an ERROR 'wm_protocol() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given'.

Comment: If you need to do more than one thing when the close box is clicked, you'll need to write a function to do all of them (a lambda is no longer really sufficient), and pass that to ``wm_protocol``.

Comment: Genius! +1 ! THANKS!